# Cinema Display / 2023 Mac Mini M2

Tags: mac-mini, cinema-display, dvi

I just read a couple of questions on apple.com describing ghosting issues and generally bad experiences connecting an older Cinema Display to an M1 Mac Mini running Big Sur.  There are no follow-ups with any resolution mentioned.

- [Issues Mac Mini M1 / HDMI-DVI Adapter (Apple) Cinema Display 23](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252231367)
- [HDMI to DVI issues Mac Mini M1](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252350793)

Can anyone out there verify whether or not this is a hardware or software issue and if it has been resolved? I have two Cinema Displays which are still working just fine and though my computer itself needs replacing, I'd really like to keep the monitors.

Comment: I’m so sorry, I inadvertently meshed two comments together which I thought  was “succinct and helpful.   NowI can’t remember what I was trying to convey.